# How can I optimize the following code

Tags: django

[color and size are taken from URL using GET method in django
color and size are check box inputs and are recieved as a list in the view.py file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/abQ9Z.png)

I am filtering my Prouct table using color and size attributes

```
mydict = dict(request.GET)

if 'size' in mydict:
       result1 = Product.objects.filter(attributes__size__in=mydict['size'])

if 'color' in mydict:
       result2 = Product.objects.filter(attributes__color__in=mydict['color'])

result = result1.intersection(result2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to use `intersection` here. A combined filter would be much better. Also, `request.GET` is already a dict.

```
result = Product.objects.all()
if 'size' in request.GET:
    result = result.filter(attributes__size__in=request.GET['size'])
if 'color' in request.GET:
    result = result.filter(attributes__color__in=request.GET['color'])
```

If you've got lots of parameters, and they all map to elements in `attributes`, you could do it dynamically:

```
result = Product.objects.all()
for key, value in request.GET:
    result = result.filter(**{'attributes__{}__in'.format(key): value})
```

Comment: But now the filter has changed i can now no longer filter by color and size simultaneously

Comment: Yes you can. Why do you think you can't? And note your original code would only work if both elements were present, it would fail if either size or color is missing.

Comment: I tried your method and I got the following result, I selected color red as in the URL and I got the result as no data but as per my data in the table I should have got 2 entries in the output